# Database Design webapp

Tags: web-services, user-interface, database-design, web-applications

Is there a webapp that lets me draw out the structure of a database and link keys visually?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a pencil and paper or whiteboard is more useful until you get your schema right.

But I've found [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/) to be a good online flowcharting solution. it supports db schema and some other useful types. You can save your work on the server and print out.